# Piping output of Vim command to shell command

Tags: shell, vim

To to find all modified files in Vim I type

```
:ls
```

This will give me a list like so

```
2  h   "index.html"                   line 98
3  h   "Category/Category.Bg_S.js"    line 1
4  h   "Category/Category.Box0_S.js"  line 1
5  +   "Category/Category.Box10_S.js" line 1
6      "Category/Category.Box11_S.js" line 1
7  +   "Category/Category.Box12_S.js" line 1
```

But if there are too many buffers this can be tedious. What I was thinking of doing would be something like:

```
:ls !grep +
```

to pipe the contents of vim's `ls` to shell's `grep` function. But it does not work. I therefore have 2 questions:

1. How do I find out the list of all modified files?
2. If there is an easier solution to 1), then how would I, for whatever reason, pass the output of a vim command to a shell command?

Comment: What do you want to do with those modified files?

Comment: @romainl I like to see what files are modified before exiting rather than blindly issuing `:xa`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to "redirect" the output to a vim variable, then filter it for modified buffers:

```
function! GetModifiedBuffers()
    redir => bufoutput
    buffers  " same as ls
    redir END
    return join(filter(split(bufoutput,'\n'),"v:val =~ '\\%8c+'"),'\n')
endfunction
```

Then do something like `:echo GetModifiedBuffers()` to show the list of modified buffers.